# Time data type defaults to datetime when creating table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

As the title says, when creating a table with a column of time type, the column defaults to datetime type. Is this normal or a bug? Here's the relevant line when creating the table:

```
Create Table dbo.time(
ColumnOfTime time)
```

And here's what's created:

```
ColumnOfTime [DATETIME Nullable]
```

Again, is this normal or have i done something wrong? Not much of a SQL person and the tinternet doesn't seem to offer much advice. Thanks

Comment: Are you really using SQL 2000? If so, I think that may be your issue, 2008 and above https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql

Comment: `TIME` is not a valid datatype in `SQL Server 2000`.  It should have given an error instead of defaulting it, but 2000 was 17 years ago and it did/does weirder things.

Comment: Sadly, it is not my choice, but yes i've had a look at that link which is why i suspected it maybe a bug? Seeing as it's out of support, is there anything that can be done to make this work?

Comment: It's not a bug.  You're trying to use a datatype that does not exist in that version.  If you want to use it, you need to update to at least `SQL Server 2008`.

Comment: Btw, there's no support from Microsoft for SQL Server 2000 anymore. If you want to do any serious work you must switch to a newer version.

Comment: @Siyual Don't you think that's a bug - when you attempt to use an invalid datatype and instead of throwing an error it replaces it with another datatype - That sounds like a bug to me?

Comment: @StanShaw it does seem like a bug as you would expect an error, OP - have you service packed all the available SPs? Otherwise, I guess lump it, it is 17 years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have SQL Server 2000, you can either use the datetime datatype, and just ignore the date portion when you work with it, or you can store time as a varchar or integer (maybe seconds after midnight) and do the necessary casting and/or calculations when you work with it.

Comment: Agreed on this, don't think you have much other option.

Comment: Okay thanks fellas, appreciate the help. Marking as answer